# pandas: Получить список месяцев между двумя датами

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mo_pG9q_43lBtauRfS2ProsFbki1ZJ-Z/view?usp=sharing), в котором для каждого уникального id прогресса указана дата начала и дата окончания работы. Как из этой разницы начальной и конечной дат получить список месяцев, в которые выполнялась работа? Т.е. на выходе я хочу построить график, который покажет, сколько уникальных id пришлось на каждый месяц, при этом, если работа выполнялась несколько месяцев, она должна учитываться в каждый месяц.

```
    progress_id                         month_start month_finish
0   e4897c239bcf0cbf7b081c8de86eb893    2018-04     NaT
1   81fb8b7412a483355d02d32987aaba6e    2018-06     2018-07
2   225784e4b9c1b3dcefc486f1e27f946b    2018-07     2019-01
3   c29cf5d7f832d3e82f99a118223eb729    2018-08     2018-08
4   b431e4ed2a994d9a8435553c52967ffe    2018-06     2018-09
```

Что пытался сделать, но так и не сообразил, как агрегировать в один столбцы с датами начала и конца: сделать `unstack()` по месяцам и заполнить месяца, в которые выполнялась работа единицами, остальное 0. Т.е. в строках - id, в столбах все месяцы от первого до последнего, на пересечении единицы между месяцем начала и месяцем конца.

Comment: Где ваш код? Где пример исходных данных? Прочитаете,  как правильно задавать вопросы.

Comment: Пример по ссылке в DataFrame, код не валидный, смысл его вставлять.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
df["month_finish"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_finish"]) # приводим данные к нужному типу
df["month_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_start"])
df = df.fillna(method="ffill", axis=1) # заполняем NaT значением, равным началу работ
```

ну и далее:

```
df["range"]=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["month_start"],
                                             x["month_finish"], freq="D"), axis=1)
# freq="D" нужна для того, чтобы поймать значения, где начало и конец работ равны
df["months"] = df["range"].apply(lambda x: set(x.month.to_list()))
```

ну и получаем df:

```
                        progress_id month_start month_finish  \
0  e4897c239bcf0cbf7b081c8de86eb893  2018-04-01   2018-04-01   
1  81fb8b7412a483355d02d32987aaba6e  2018-06-01   2018-07-01   
2  225784e4b9c1b3dcefc486f1e27f946b  2018-07-01   2019-01-01   
3  c29cf5d7f832d3e82f99a118223eb729  2018-08-01   2018-08-01   
4  b431e4ed2a994d9a8435553c52967ffe  2018-06-01   2018-09-01   

                                               range                    months  
0  DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-01'], dtype='datetime6...                       {4}  
1  DatetimeIndex(['2018-06-01', '2018-06-02', '20...                    {6, 7}  
2  DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-01', '2018-07-02', '20...  {1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}  
3  DatetimeIndex(['2018-08-01'], dtype='datetime6...                       {8}  
4  DatetimeIndex(['2018-06-01', '2018-06-02', '20...              {8, 9, 6, 7}
```

Comment: У меня ругается, `Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid.  Use data.to_timestamp() instead`, но когда пытаюсь использовать `to_timestamp` сыпется `cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: Где именно у вас возникает ошибка? у меня с вашим датафреймом из вопроса все отлично работает.